# What's the rationale behind this pulse shaping function?

Tags: ofdm

Section 13.2 of [the HD Radio standard for AM](http://www.nrscstandards.org/SG/NRSC-5-C/1012sf.pdf) defines a pulse shaping function that appears to be some strange variant on a raised cosine filter:

[image]

[image]

More specifically, H(ξ) is a raised cosine filter with total width (1+α)T, and W(ξ) appears to be a "stretched" version. Why do they do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pulse envelope is convolved with a Gaussian function to soften the transition between the symbols. If the standard pulse envelope were used without any softening, it would be audible to an AM detector (it runs at ~172 Hz).

Source: Chapter 8 of The IBOC Handbook: Understanding HD Radio (TM) Technology by David P. Maxson

Comment: Any chance of a page reference? :-)

Comment: Chapter 8 is the best I can do. I was using the Google Books preview. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It may be to constrain a symbol within the period to mitigate ISI. There may be other properties that become apparent in practical application over more traditional tapers. It could be the result of research combined with analysis of real world data.

Given the paper doesn't cite any source, you may have to do some more research on pulse-shaping and OFDM in scholarly publications. Maybe there's a paper out there that has more information or a comparison of windowing functions.